# comparison of two excel sheet and write output

Tags: python-3.x, xlrd, xlwt

Am writing a python code using xlrd and xlwt to compare two excel sheet and writing output in third sheet.
For example

```
Sheet 1
nativeEMSName
HR_MEWT_XX5906_TR_I_HR10001
HR_LOHN_5811X_T01_C_X_HO55001
HR_PHKL_XX6541_TR_I_HR10001
HR_RWRI_XX3608_TR_I_HR10001
HR_KTHL_XX6382_AR_I_HR50001
ABC
HR_KURU_XX3714_TR_I_HR10001
HR_RWRI_XX1142_TR_I_HR10001
HR_SAHU_SAHUW_B01_C_X_EX10001
HR_KTHL_XX3622_TR_I_HR10001
```

```
Sheet2
nativeEMSName                   id
HR_KURU_XX3714_TR_I_HR10001     66
HR_PHKL_XX6541_TR_I_HR10001     999
HR_MEWT_XX5906_TR_I_HR10001     2
HR_KTHL_XX6382_AR_I_HR50001     7777
HR_KTHL_XX3622_TR_I_HR10001     4
HR_SAHU_SAHUW_B01_C_X_EX10001   3
HR_LOHN_5811X_T01_C_X_HO55001   111
HR_RWRI_XX1142_TR_I_HR10001     55
HR_RWRI_XX3608_TR_I_HR10001     888
```

am finding sheet1's nativeEMSName in sheet2 and write nativeEMSName and respective ID in sheeet3.
Below code is using for same

```py
conls=0
colnd=0

for rowsr in range(sheet1.nrows):
    test=sheet1.cell(rowsr,colns).value
    for rowdr in range(sheet2.nrows):
        test1=sheet2.cell(rowdr,colnd).value
        if test==test1:
            ID = sheet2.cell(rowdr, colnd +1).value
            sheet3.write(rowsr,colns,ID)
            sheet3.write(rowsr,colnd+1,test1)
            wb.save('test.xls')
            break
```

But the challenge is when noumber of row is like 30k in both sheet then code taking too much time to execute. I want to reduce execution time. 
Any help will appreciate to optimize this code or use another way to get output in shortest time.

Answer (score 0):

Your look-up is **O(mxn)** where m is number of rows in sheet1, n is number of rows in sheet2.

I assume there are no duplicates. I think this will work better. It is also easy to find bugs because you have data in map

**1. Read sheet1 into a list**

```
sheet1_list = [HR_MEWT_XX5906_TR_I_HR10001,
HR_LOHN_5811X_T01_C_X_HO55001,
HR_PHKL_XX6541_TR_I_HR10001,
HR_RWRI_XX3608_TR_I_HR10001, and_so_on.. ]
```

**2. Read sheet2 (look-up sheet) into a map**

```
sheet2_map = {
'HR_KURU_XX3714_TR_I_HR10001'  : '66',
'HR_PHKL_XX6541_TR_I_HR10001'  : '999',
'HR_MEWT_XX5906_TR_I_HR10001'  :   '2,
'HR_KTHL_XX6382_AR_I_HR50001'  :  '7777',
<So on..>
}
```

**3. Loop list and find id,** 
Here, individual look up is O(1), and **total time is O(n)**, n is number of entries in sheet1, hence reduces time.

```
for key in sheet1_list:
   print(key, sheet2_map[key]) #check by print
   sheet3_map[key] = sheet2_map[key] # inserts key:id, like {'HR_MEWT_XX5906_TR_I_HR10001': '2' }
```

**4. convert_map_to_excel**( sheet3_map) , 
there are libraries but, its easy, use xlwt to write xls. https://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/